# Loop Sequence break under map function after await

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

I am newbie on Async Await promise approach. Learn very basic part of async & await. I am at situation where I want to execute the task sequentially, Now for this I wrote the Code but there loop will break the sequence.

My Code is this:

```
const myAsyncFunction = async () => {
    try {
        let db1Data = await MyCollection1Name.find().exec();
        if (db1Data.length > 0) {
            //Suppose this collection have sector element which is array and have 5 values
            let newData = db1Data[0].sector;

            await Promise.all(
                newData.map(async(x, i) => {
                    let db2Data = await MyCollection2Name.find().exec();
                    console.log(i)// Here My loop is break. It not print the value in sequential order. Although this will call after await

                })
            )
        }
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
    }
}
myAsyncFunction()
```

Can anyone guide me where I am doing mistake??

Any help or suggestions is really appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

The functions within the map are asynchronous so return a promise. They will start executing in order, but may not finish in the same order. The await on Promise.all will return the mapped array in the correct order though.

If you want to do them in order, then use reduce like this:

```
newData.reduce(
    async (acc, curr) => acc.then(res => MyCollection2Name.find().exec()),
    Promise.resolve()
)
```

Comment: So it means there is no use of await Promise.all()?

Comment: And really appreciate for giving the suggestion

Comment: No worries :) If you just want the results in order but don't care what order they are executed in, then what you have at the moment will work, you just need to make sure you return from within the map function.

Comment: If order of execution does matter, then the code snippet above is the general idea of what you will need.